# Why doesn't LIKE's percentage % match new lines with this query?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot, newline, sql-like, google-query-language

Any ideas why LIKE doesn't find a word in multiple lines cell if we are trying to pivot results

Example below:

[We have a table, where 1st line has 2 lines in cell][image: 1]

if i do query and try to pivot results the line which has 2 lines is ignoring as a result and not posted in pivot table
Formula as follows

> =QUERY(B:G;"SELECT D, E, SUM(F), AVG(F) WHERE B IS NOT NULL AND B LIKE '%"&H1&"%' GROUP BY D,E pivot C")

[Result][image: 2]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IjdsKJK_sXCn-Syv3Lh4wfR5jmCy2Vp6YqHzVspUCw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Apparently `%` doesn't include new lines `\n`

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=QUERY(B:G; 
 "select D,E,sum(F),avg(F) 
  where B is not null 
    and B contains '"&H1&"' 
  group by D,E 
  pivot C")
```

[image]

Comment: thx, i used contains, but from knowledge part -  trying to figure out the reasons why LIKE is not working properly?

Comment: @Nonameisname see the detailed documentation: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where nah, never mind, it is not mentioned there at all to save the ink needed to print all characters on the page and save the planet. I have no idea why but it's proven by many occasions that QUERY is the most unreliable formula